# PermissionError: [Errno13] Permission denied: 'text.txt' (after compiling with cx_freeze)

Tags: python, permissions, cx-freeze

I created a game using pygame and crated .msi file with cx_freeze.

I have also created `high score feature` by creating a text file storing high score and comparing player's score every time the game ended.

If the score is higher than the high score, it will overwrite the text file, else `text.close()`.

Before using `cx_freeze`, `.py` file works fine with `text.txt` file in the same directory. However, after creating `.msi` file and install on my laptop, this message appeared.

[image: This showed up after game over]

I have included the `high_score.txt` file in the same directory.

Another weird thing is that, with `py setup.py bdist_msi` command, it created build and dist folders. build folder contains entire game which can be played without installation. The game works fine here.

However, when I installed with `.msi` file and play the game in Program Files/Jumper(game folder), the error message appeared.

Comment: Did you run the program as administrator?(Something like this, however I haven't used Microsoft Windows for long time...)

Comment: Thanks so much Kelvin. Now the program works. This means that player needs to run the program as administrator all the time by right click --> run as administrator. Is there a way to set this automatically ? I supposed there must be some options during compiling.

Comment: Yes you can, check [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/505114/how-to-always-run-as-administrator-applications-on-windows-8) at SuperUser.